# Genymotion RAM usage increas 8MB everytime I take screenshot via ADB

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

Every time I take screenshot by invoke `adb shell screencap -p` in terminal, the `player` process show increasing RAM usage about 8MB permanently. This makes make program become unstable in long run. How to stop this memory leak?

My setup:
Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Guest OS: Android 9.0 API 28
Genymotion : 3.0.4
VirtualBox : 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion 3.0.4 support is coming to an end as 3.1 will be released soon; it won't receive any more updates or fixes.
It would be best to try with the upcoming new version or try with the beta version instead.